# Show that $\tau$ is a Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a arbitrary set and let $A\subset X$ fix. Show that $\tau=\{O\subset X: A\subset O\}\cup \{\varnothing\}$ is a topology in $X$.

Hello, my problem is show that the finite intersection of set belongs a $\tau$? The first axiom is clear, because $\varnothing, X\in \tau.$ Furthermore, the arbitrary union of elements of $\tau$, belongs a $\tau$. We have that $A_i\subset \displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\in \tau.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $O_1 \in \tau,\, O_2 \in \tau$, we could assume that $A \subset O_1$ and $A \subset O_2$, and thus $A \subset O_1 \cap O_2$. So $O_1 \cap O_2 \in \tau$. If our assumption above does not hold, then either $O_1$ or $O_2$ is $\emptyset$, and their intersection is still in $\tau$.

Your proof about union is not quite correct, notice that $A$ is fixed, and is used to define the topology. So you need to show that $A \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in I}O_{\alpha} $ for $O_{\alpha}\in \tau$ (notice at most one $O_{\alpha_0}=\emptyset$), which is obviously true by the definition of set-unions.

Comment: There is also the special case yo consider when say $O_1 = \varnothing$. In which case $O_1 \cap O_2 = \varnothing \in \tau$.

Comment: @benguin good point, I'll update my answer

Comment: Additionally any intersection of open sets is open.

Comment: @WilliamElliot No, not any intersection, but only finite intersection, and that's what I showed in my first paragraph - if intersection of two open sets is open, so is finite intersections.

Comment: @zha That any intersection of sets that contain A, contains A is simple set theory.  It stills holds for the empty intersection, a finite case of special concern.  In the case that A is empty, the topology is discrete.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yea, I agree. But here we only need to show finite intersection is closed. And I know it is obvious, but I just laid it out in first paragraph. And my edit include a case that A is not empty, but one of the open set is empty. Could you point out which step you are talking about? I still could not relate your comment to my answer.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I think you might missed one information from the question that empty set is always in the topology even when A is not empty, i.e. The topology is defined by super sets of A; but PLUS the empty set which does not need to be superset of A. That's why I discussed the empty set in my proof. Hope that answered your doubt.